# Is there a way to apply differential privacy on an entire dataset?

Tags: python, privacy

I'm currently trying to find a way to apply Differential Privacy on an entire dataset to anonymize this dataset.

I read that, to release multiple statistics about the same user, I have to add a laplace noise of scale C/espilon with C the number of statistics (https://desfontain.es/privacy/differential-privacy-in-practice.html).

Then I have two main questions :

- If I have a dataset of C features, can I add a laplace Noise of of scale C/espilon on this dataset to obtain an epsilon-differentially private dataset ?
- If this is possible, how can I handle categorical features ?

Thanks for help !

I wrote a simple function to add laplace noise on a dataset :

```
def Noise(df, epsilon):
    noisy_df = df.copy()
    
    scale = epsilon/df.shape[1]
    noise = np.random.laplace(0, scale, df.shape)
    noisy_df += noise

    return noisy_df
```